# pcl use of shared pointers, does it make copies?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, point-cloud-library

So i have been using the `pcl` `SampleConsensus` module to do some line fitting and i found something awfully strange with the `pcl` point cloud usage. I am currently ransacing to find the most prominent line, then i retrieve only the outliers from the cloud and ransac on it again.

So to perform ransac on a cloud say i have some setup:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr dataCloud(shared_ptr_cloud_from_elsewhere);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr outlierCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::SampleConsensusModelLine<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr modelLine(
    new pcl::SampleConsensusModelLine<pcl::PointXYZ>(dataCloud));

//Pay careful attention to line below because its position determines 
//if the code is going to work or not
pcl::SampleConsensusModelLine<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr modelLine2(
    new pcl::SampleConsensusModelLine<pcl::PointXYZ>(outlierCloud));

pcl::RandomSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZ> ransac(modelLine);
ransac.compute();
ransac.inliers(inliers);
```

Using `ExtractIndices` I retrieve the outliers from the negative of the list of inliers and i put them in the `outlierCloud`. `outlierCloud` is checked and definitely has points in it. Then all i should have to do is change the model `ransac` is using and go again:

```
ransac.setSampleConsensusModel(modelLine2)
ransac.compute(); //This will fail, due to having no points.
```

So `ransac.compute()` fails, but why? `modelLine2` is defined and has a pointer to the cloud `outlierCloud` which definitely has points?

So that line i said to pay attention to, if you move it so that `modelLine2` is defined after `outlierCloud` is filled out then it works just fine. Same example same everything.

This suggests to me that `pcl` is taking a deep copy of this cloud even though it requests a shared pointer to it? Isn't this insanely bad? There are no scope changes or anything funny happening on my end, so why do i have to create `modelLine2` after the data has been filled in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deep copy is made but the [constructor](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/sac__model_8h_source.html#l00108) of SampleConsusModel internally calls its [setInputCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/sac__model_8h_source.html#l00304) method which stores (as expected) the pointer to the cloud and **resizes the set of indices** of the points to use to the *current* size of the cloud (to `0` in your case). So the pointer is correct but the model uses `0` indices for the cloud it is pointing to.

As a workaround you could call `setInputCloud` yourself after `outlierCloud` is filled.